# Como validar el campo @id_facturas que no inserte datos repetidos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo un cursor que inserta datos de una tabla a otra , lo que sucede es que quiero validar el campo id facturas ya que es una primary key , no quiero que se repita .
Este es mi cursor :

```
DECLARE @id_facturas int,@MedicoID int,
@UsuariID int,
@CLIENTE VARCHAR(60),
@FechaRecepion datetime,
@FechaDocumento datetime,
@FechaCliente datetime,
@FechaMedik datetime,
@FechaVencimiento datetime,
@nroSerie char(4),
@nroFactura varchar(20),
@monto numeric(18,2),
@montoIGV numeric(18,2),
@montobruto numeric(18,2),
@tipodocumento CHAR(2),
@montohoteleria numeric(18,2),
@montoterapia numeric(18,2),
@montofarmacia numeric(18,2),
@montoexamen numeric(18,2),
@montohonorario numeric(18,2),
@montoOtro numeric(18,2),
@Estado char(1),
@FechaAprobacion datetime,
@FechaObservada datetime,
@FechaAdjuntada datetime,
@Enviado bit,
@auditorID int,
@EstadoReuditado char(1),
@ReauditorID int,
@FacturaIDAnt int,
@FechaHospitalizacionInicio datetime,
@FechaHospitalizacionFin datetime,
@MotivoFactura varchar(50),
@diasHospitalizacion int

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE insert_CHUBB CURSOR FOR
select [id_facturas],2 as [MedicoID],17 AS [UsuarioID],'CHUBB ACCIDENTES PERSONALES' AS [CLIENTE] ,fech_registro AS[FechaRecepcion],
fech_doc as [FechaDocumento],'' as [FechaCliente],'' as [FechaMedik],'' as [FechaVencimiento],CASE
WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5 ),'-',''))<4THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,6),'-','')
WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5 ),'-',''))=4THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5),'-','')
 ELSE '' END AS [nroSerie]
,CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5 ),'-',''))<4 THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(NRO_DOC,6,20),'-','')
WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,6 ),'-',''))=4THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(NRO_DOC,6,20),'-','') ELSE '' END AS [nroFactura],
imp_neto as [Monto],
imp_igv as [MontoIGV],
imp_bruto as [MontoBruto],
ctipo_doc as [Tipo Documento],
imp_hoteleria as [MontoHoteleria],
imp_teparia as [Monto Terapia],
imp_farmacia as [Monto Farmacia],
imp_examenes as [Monto Examen],
imp_honorarios as [Monto Honorario],
imp_otros as [Monto Otro],
cestado as [Estado],
CASE WHEN cestado='A' then fecha_aprobacion else null end as [Fecha Aprobacion],
CASE WHEN cestado='X' then FechaCartaObservada else null end as [Fecha Observada],
'' as [Fecha Adjuntada],
benviado as [ENVIADO],
'' as [AuditorID],
'' as [Estado Reauditado],
'' as [ReauditorID],
'' as [FacturaIDAnt],
'' as [FechaHospitalizacionInicio],
'' as [FechaHospitalizacionFin],
'' as [MotivoFactura],
'' as [diasHospitalizacion]
from SAMK_AP_ACE.dbo.Facturas where ctipo_doc='NC'



OPEN insert_CHUBB
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_CHUBB INTO @id_facturas ,@MedicoID,
@UsuariID,
@CLIENTE,
@FechaRecepion ,
@FechaDocumento ,
@FechaCliente ,
@FechaMedik ,
@FechaVencimiento ,
@nroSerie ,
@nroFactura ,
@monto ,
@montoIGV ,
@montobruto ,
@tipodocumento ,
@montohoteleria ,
@montoterapia ,
@montofarmacia ,
@montoexamen ,
@montohonorario,
@montoOtro ,
@Estado ,
@FechaAprobacion,
@FechaObservada ,
@FechaAdjuntada ,
@Enviado ,
@auditorID ,
@EstadoReuditado ,
@ReauditorID,
@FacturaIDAnt ,
@FechaHospitalizacionInicio ,
@FechaHospitalizacionFin ,
@MotivoFactura ,
@diasHospitalizacion

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO FACTURACION.DBO.Factura
SELECT @id_facturas ,@MedicoID ,
@UsuariID ,
@CLIENTE ,
@FechaRecepion ,
@FechaDocumento ,
@FechaCliente ,
@FechaMedik ,
@FechaVencimiento ,
@nroSerie ,
@nroFactura ,
@monto ,
@montoIGV ,
@montobruto ,
@tipodocumento ,
@montohoteleria ,
@montoterapia ,
@montofarmacia ,
@montoexamen ,
@montohonorario,
@montoOtro ,
@Estado ,
@FechaAprobacion,
@FechaObservada ,
@FechaAdjuntada ,
@Enviado ,
@auditorID ,
@EstadoReuditado ,
@ReauditorID,
@FacturaIDAnt ,
@FechaHospitalizacionInicio ,
@FechaHospitalizacionFin ,
@MotivoFactura ,
@diasHospitalizacion

FETCH NEXT FROM insert_CHUBB into @id_facturas ,@MedicoID ,
@UsuariID ,
@CLIENTE ,
@FechaRecepion ,
@FechaDocumento ,
@FechaCliente ,
@FechaMedik ,
@FechaVencimiento ,
@nroSerie ,
@nroFactura ,
@monto ,
@montoIGV ,
@montobruto ,
@tipodocumento ,
@montohoteleria ,
@montoterapia ,
@montofarmacia ,
@montoexamen ,
@montohonorario,
@montoOtro ,
@Estado ,
@FechaAprobacion,
@FechaObservada ,
@FechaAdjuntada ,
@Enviado ,
@auditorID ,
@EstadoReuditado ,
@ReauditorID,
@FacturaIDAnt ,
@FechaHospitalizacionInicio ,
@FechaHospitalizacionFin ,
@MotivoFactura ,
@diasHospitalizacion

END

CLOSE insert_CHUBB

DEALLOCATE insert_CHUBB
```

El idfactura no es un identity .

Comment: Por qué utilizar un cursor cuando puedes hacer todo con un solo insert?

Answer (score 0):

En tu tabla tendrías que definirla como llave primaria o única

```
ALTER TABLE DBO.Factura ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Facturas UNIQUE (id_facturas);
```

O

```
ALTER TABLE DBO.Factura ALTER COLUMN id_facturas int NOT NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE DBO.Factura ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Facturas PRIMARY KEY (id_facturas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta opción te permite validar al momento de insertar que no se incluyan facturas que no ya existan en la tabla `Facturacion.dbo.factura`. Pero no evita que la consulta tenga duplicados. Eso se podría validar con CONSTRAINTs como lo propuso Dixroby.

```
INSERT INTO FACTURACION.DBO.Factura
SELECT [id_facturas],
    2 as [MedicoID],
    17 AS [UsuarioID],
    'CHUBB ACCIDENTES PERSONALES' AS [CLIENTE] ,
    fech_registro AS[FechaRecepcion],
    fech_doc as [FechaDocumento],
    '' as [FechaCliente],
    '' as [FechaMedik],
    '' as [FechaVencimiento],
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5 ),'-',''))<4THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,6),'-','')
        WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5 ),'-',''))=4THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5),'-','')
        ELSE '' END AS [nroSerie]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,5 ),'-',''))<4 THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(NRO_DOC,6,20),'-','')
        WHEN LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(nro_doc,0,6 ),'-',''))=4THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(NRO_DOC,6,20),'-','') 
        ELSE '' END AS [nroFactura],
    imp_neto as [Monto],
    imp_igv as [MontoIGV],
    imp_bruto as [MontoBruto],
    ctipo_doc as [Tipo Documento],
    imp_hoteleria as [MontoHoteleria],
    imp_teparia as [Monto Terapia],
    imp_farmacia as [Monto Farmacia],
    imp_examenes as [Monto Examen],
    imp_honorarios as [Monto Honorario],
    imp_otros as [Monto Otro],
    cestado as [Estado],
    CASE WHEN cestado='A' then fecha_aprobacion else null end as [Fecha Aprobacion],
    CASE WHEN cestado='X' then FechaCartaObservada else null end as [Fecha Observada],
    '' as [Fecha Adjuntada],
    benviado as [ENVIADO],
    '' as [AuditorID],
    '' as [Estado Reauditado],
    '' as [ReauditorID],
    '' as [FacturaIDAnt],
    '' as [FechaHospitalizacionInicio],
    '' as [FechaHospitalizacionFin],
    '' as [MotivoFactura],
    '' as [diasHospitalizacion]
FROM SAMK_AP_ACE.dbo.Facturas sf
WHERE ctipo_doc='NC'
AND NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM FACTURACION.DBO.Factura ff
                WHERE ff.id_facturas = sf.id_facturas);
```